# Compress Column in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am looking to compress a column through Liquibase and I haven't been able to find any examples of this on the Liquidbase site.

I was wondering if anyone has an example of this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "compress"? If this is a database feature then you can run arbitrary SQL with http://liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql

Comment: I should of been more clear. I'm looking to compress the content that is stored in a column. I know this is possible in oracle 11g

Comment: @Fraser Liquibase can only manage the SQL issued against your database. It can't create functionality that is not supported by the underlying database technology. If you know how to do this in Oracle then I would suggest creating a SQL based migration, as suggested by Christoph.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I don't know much about Liquidbase and didn't know you could issue SQL commands direct. Apparently this isn't natively supported by Liquidbase so you have to send the command for each database engine

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom SQL statements to [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) change logs using the `<sql>` element and use the `dbms` attribute on change sets to define for which databases they are meant to be run.

```
<changeSet id=".." dbms="oracle">
  <sql>
    alter table foobar move compress;
  </sql>
  <rollback>
   <sql>
     alter table foobar nocompress;
   </sql>
  </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [modifyDataType](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html)

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="modifyDataType-example">
    <modifyDataType catalogName="cat"
            columnName="id"
            newDataType="A String"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="person"/>
</changeSet>
```